# Karaf - Unable to resolve: missing requirement (osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))])

Tags: jms, apache-karaf, karaf

I'm trying to install bundle on Karaf but but I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve axsjmsblueprintcaller [56](R 56.0): missing requirement [axsjmsblueprintcaller [56](R 56.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve javax.jms-api [58](R 58.0): missing requirement [javax.jms-api [58](R 58.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.transaction.xa)] Unresolved requirements: [[axsjmsblueprintcaller [56](R 56.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jms)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Install.execute(Install.java:96)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.4]
... 11 more
```

After that i'm trying to download javax.jms(javax.jms-api version 2.0.1) and copy it to deploy folder on karaf and run it again but it's still throw that exeption.

Karaf cannot start the bundle. Please help me!

Comment: Did you solved this problem?